# jQuery Navbar li align center on scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap Navbar that uses the .affix class with an offset of 100px. The navbar list items are centered in the bar by default. When the .affix class is triggered, I have jQuery show the navbar-brand in the navbar on the left and push the list items to the right. When you scroll back up within the 100px, the navbar brand disappears and the list items should go back to center, but they return slightly off center. I created a codepen, but it actually works fine in the codepen for some reason.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Tambe257/pen/WwYoEO

If I click on a menu item, they then center themselves, allowing me to click again and follow the link. Here's the code:

html:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-info">
    <h1><span class="heavy">John Doe</span> Rosenthal</h1>
    <h2>Licensed Real Estate Salesperson</h2>
    <img src="img/coach-logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
</div>
</header>

<!--     nav      -->
<div class="nav-wrapper">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="right-nav">
        <li><a href="#current-listings" class="page-scroll">Current Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="sales.html" class="page-scroll">Sales Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="page-scroll">About John Doe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Get In Touch</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
margin: 0;
background: $maroon;
@include border-radius(0px);
z-index: 5;

a {
  color: $white;
}

a.navbar-brand {
 display: none;
 font-family: $main-font;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
 }

 a.navbar-brand:hover {
 color: $white * 0.7;
 font-size: 24px;
 }

li {
 float: none;
display: inline-block;

a, a.page-scroll {
  color: $white;
  font-size: 1.6rem;

  &:visited, &:focus {
    color: $white;  
  }

  &:hover {
    color: $white * 0.7;
  }
 }
}

}

.navbar-default, .navbar-collapse {
 border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: $white;
 font-size: 1.6rem;

&:hover {
color: $white * 0.7;
}
}

.nav-wrapper {
 min-height: 50px;  
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,     .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
color: $white;
font-size: 1.6rem;

 &:hover {
 color: $white * 0.7;
}
}

.navbar-nav {
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nav').affix({


offset: {
    top: 100
  }
});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  $('#nav').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('affix')) {
      $('.navbar-brand').fadeIn(500);
      $('#right-nav').addClass('navbar-right');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-brand').fadeOut(500);
      $('#right-nav').removeClass('navbar-right');
      $('navbar-nav').attr('float: none', 'text-align: center');
    }
  });
});
```

Maybe there's just a better way to write the jQuery. Again, it works properly in the codepen, but not in any browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what the issue is, and it's easier than I expected. It is actually happening in the Codepen that I posted above, but the it's only slightly off center, so it isn't as noticeable.

The issue is that I am fading out the navbar-brand over 500ms, but the centering of the navbar-nav is happening immediately. The navbar-nav gets to the center as far as it can go, and then bumps into the navbar-brand, which still hasn't finished fading out, and stops.

If I change the jQuery to .hide() it works fine:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {


$('#nav').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('affix')) {
      $('.navbar-brand').fadeIn(500);
      $('#right-nav').addClass('navbar-right');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-brand').hide();
      $('#right-nav').removeClass('navbar-right');
      $('navbar-nav').attr('float: none', 'text-align: center');
    }
  });
});
```